# How can I implement a shopping cart with cloud firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a food delivery application with the design of [CS Guys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWH66F9y63U&t=597s) from YouTube, I've already done the authentication part and have already tried multiple ways to add the cart to firestore (creating a collection in the document of each user and that collection will consist the document of fooditem user has added to the cart) and after that on the click of button "place order" I want to make sure all the data which currently exists in the cart goes to another collection known as order or just a field in the document which will refer the documents of fooditem which is already in the separate collection known as fooditem where every item has a unique id.

Comment: Have you found out the solution ? because i do have the same problem.

Comment: @Shivas yeah I did, first encode the data to jason then send it